Not maintane gap one to other perfectly
isotop js no working properly it stay one over one. Not maintain gap perfectly how can i solve? Can anyone have any idea?
$('.masonary-wrapper-activation').imagesLoaded(function () {
                // filter items on button click
                $('.messonry-button').on('click', 'button', function () {
                    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                    $(this).siblings('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
                    $(this).addClass('is-checked');
                    $grid.isotope({
                        filter: filterValue
                    });
                });

                // init Isotope
                var $grid = $('.mesonry-list').isotope({
                    percentPosition: true,
                    transitionDuration: '0.7s',
                    layoutMode: 'masonry',
                    masonry: {
                        columnWidth: '.resizer',
                    }
                });
            });

Not maintain gap one to other perfectly how can i solve? Can anyone have any idea?

Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.
